# How to copy some type files in Linux

Tags: bash, shell

If I would like to `scp` all the files in the current directory except `*m` files (matlab code) to a remote server, how could I manage to do this? In particular using bash script.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Hm, `rsync` over `ssh` might be simpler if you want filters, but keep a directory structure.

Comment: maybe it's a silly question, but what's wrong with `scp ... *[^m]` to copy all files except those who end in `m`?

Comment: @cluracan: it can becode a problem if you have some subdirectories which also need to be filtered. If just a flat dir without deeper levels: no problem at all.

Comment: @Wrikken ah, right. Multiple subdirectories. Well, in that case use `find`? Although building the directory tree on the remote server (if it can change) will be a pain...

Answer (score 0):

use recursive scp:

```
scp -r ... *[^m]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directory structure is complex, one trick is to use `tar`

```
tar c --exclude="*.m" . | ssh remote_server "tar x -C /some/directory/"
```

It furthermore preserves ownership, permission, symlinks, etc.